# How can I get bash to show the commands being executed _including_ redirections?

Tags: bash

For example in some shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x # Turn on show commands
echo hello >out
```

Output:

```
+ echo hello
```

The redirection is not shown in the command output, what needs to be done so that the full command being executed including any explicit redirection is shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "set -v":

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x # Turn on show commands
set -v
echo hello >out
$ foo.sh
+ set -v
echo hello >out
+ echo hello
```

Probably won't want the -x with this.

More set options [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin)